# Ellipsize is shown before max limit

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis, ellipsize

I have a Textview in one of the layouts to show email address. So for long email addresses the text should show ellipsis at the end and for that I have added below attributes in TextView

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:maxLines="1"
```

xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="abcabc.abcabc.100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000@abcabcabcabcabcabc.com" />
```

This works well except for one scenario where the email address has any numbers in it and a dot before the numbers for eg.

> abcabc.abcabc.100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000@abcabcabcabcabcabc.com

For above email address the ellipsis is shown before max limit like so,
[image]

If there is no dot before the numbers then ellipsis is shown properly at the end

> abcabc.abcabc100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000@abcabcabcabcabcabc.com

[image]

I am using Samsung galaxy Tab A having API 22.

Not sure why the ellipsis is shown before max limit for first scenario, how can we resolve this?

Comment: add `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it didn’t work though, the text is seen to max limit but won’t show ellipsis

Comment: very strange case.

Comment: Kindly share the xml code for the Textview, so we could have more info. about the properties you must have set in XML layout file for that TextView.

Comment: @Avi I've added it the post

Comment: Can you try with singleLine="true" instead of maxLine=1, though It has been deprecated, but try once

Comment: that actually worked, thanks!

Comment: @musica, to make ellipse work properly as expected, you should always try and keep the width of TextView to "match_parent". However, I believe you are playing with weights here... So you could also try keeping minLine = 1 and maxLine = 1 both, instead of signleLine = "true"(as this is deprecated now).